# Is [xcopy] an appropriate subject for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I recently voted to close a question tagged with [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcopy) asking about xcopy syntax. It seemed pretty cut and dry to me: Xcopy is a Windows command, so the question is more appropriate for Superuser.

The asker mentioned in the comments that there are hundreds of questions tagged with [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcopy), which is correct. It's generally in conjunction with a question about batch files, which seems kosher to me -- having a problem with writing a batch file is different than having trouble using a Windows command.

Is there a line? If not, where should the line be drawn? Is [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcopy) superfluous?

For context, here are a few examples that I would personally put into the "not about programming" category:

- [Copying files with a specific extension from multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379073/copying-files-with-a-specific-extension-from-multiple-directories)
- [XCopy one directory to another, starting from lowest size folder up-to the biggest folder in size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31692442/xcopy-one-directory-to-another-starting-from-lowest-size-folder-up-to-the-bigge)
- [When moving files XCopy can put them into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30635835/when-moving-files-xcopy-can-put-them-into-a-file)

And some that *involve* xcopy, but are fundamentally batch file or programming tools related questions:

- [Can i reference a variable in my xcopy path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404738/can-i-reference-a-variable-in-my-xcopy-path)
- [Autorun a Batch and Remove a second Row on a logfile with my Batch program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364680/autorun-a-batch-and-remove-a-second-row-on-a-logfile-with-my-batch-program)
- [Post Build event xcopy - exclude some set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044418/post-build-event-xcopy-exclude-some-set-of-files)

Comment: Does he ask a programming-question? No? Then it unequivocally doesn't belong.

Comment: Difficult, programmers always run xcopy from a batch file and it doesn't behave different from shell commands like copy.  If that's off topic then there are 56 thousand [bash] questions that need a review.  But sure, feel free to CV it as "general computing hardware and software", superuser can answer it as well.

Comment: xcopy is frequently used in a batch file, and therefore questions about it's use are on-topic IMO. Whether a single question is about the command line use or batch file use seems pretty irrelevant, as the same exact question that said *in a batch file* would be 100% on topic. (I can probably send a comment to the poster to make that edit, which would remove your objection completely.) While *relatively* strict adherence to the guidelines is important, *absolute, 100% without even a miniscule deviation due to splitting hairs over four words* seems a little excessive.

Comment: @KenWhite: No, the same question saying "in a batch file" isn't on-topic.  Programming is the art of automating things, if the user doesn't know how to do it *once*, they aren't ready to automate.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Beg to differ. If the question stated "I have this xcopy statement in a batch file, but it doesn't do what I expect. <specifics>", it's clearly on topic according to the site guidelines. (I clearly don't need to link to those guidelines, but batch programming is an acceptable topic on SO, as are bash scripts and cron jobs and Powershell scripts.) If the first time they attempt to do it happens to be in a batch script, what difference does that make?

Comment: @KenWhite: As part of their basic troubleshooting, they need to have tried it outside the batch file (substituting variables as necessary, adding `echo` in front of the line is a good way to get the command).  If they've run the copy by hand using some other command, I'd probably give them the benefit of the doubt.  But if their permissions aren't set right, no amount of batch programming help will get them over the hill -- they need to run the utility once by hand, successfully, before trying to script it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I happened to see the question being discussed (I commented on it; I'll find it again - it would have been nice if the poster here linked it for reference). IIRC, it mentioned environmental expansion (`%SomeVar%`), which probably indicates it was being used in a batch. In any case, looking at the first page or two of [tag:batch-script] questions shows tons of questions by posters who didn't know that *basic troubleshooting* includes adding `echo` at the front of the line, and that didn't make the question off-topic here.

Comment: @KenWhite: Well, string concatenation via variable interpolation is obviously a programming topic, even if no batch file is involved.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Seems the question has been deleted anyway (I can't find my comment), so I can't find the link. It was a reasonable (albeit not perfect) question, IMO. I'd thought about commenting to Daniel Mann regarding the close vote at the time, but used the space to comment to the poster of the question instead.

Comment: @KenWhite: It does sound as though the question was using at least one command shell programming feature -- but `xcopy` wasn't that feature.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because decisions whether a tag is appropriate or not is dependent on context, and there is no context or link provided in this question for reference. For example, [tag:bash] could be considered off-topic, unless the question actually referred to a scripting topic, and [tag:windows] or [tag:android] could be off-topic if they didn't refer to programming for that OS, but they're included on tons of questions that are completely appropriate for this site.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for the feedback! I updated the question with a few examples to provide context.

Comment: Your first "not about programming" example is on-topic -- it's a programming question about for loops.  `xcopy` is used, but not the topic.

Comment: The answer is no, for all cases. This is some command shell stuff, nothing related to programming or code at all. K thx bi.

Comment: Now i feel guilty because i made a question long time ago regarding PostgresSQL backup command `pg_dump.exe`

Comment: Really in my opinion, *stackoverflow* and *superuser* could have been just 1 platform. Actually, it would be great if questions could be linked to multiple platforms. I had the same problem with a question about *arduino* that really was a general *electronics* matter. And a question about *physics* that envolved *statistics* and *mathematics*. I mean, it's not like these platforms are competing. Why not just share.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If it's asking about programming with `xcopy` (quirks within a batch file, usually) then it's on topic. If it's asking about general use of xcopy (from the command line, usually), it isn't. If it could be either, err on the side of not forcing a migration/delete-and-repost and let it live here. It won't kill anyone to have a few (thousand) questions that are just slightly sort of almost a shade off-topic.

Put another way, the rules we have are there to prevent problems; if no problems are being prevented by a rule, it doesn't matter much.

Comment: +1 for "the rules we have are there to prevent problems"

Comment: A batch file is just a series of command line statements. How is there a realistic distinction between the two?

Comment: @corsiKa: ... really? A batch file can be run by scheduled tasks, random end users, etc, etc, etc; logically, then, a robust batch file must be *programmed* to handle conditions that an interactive command-line session user would have to manually understand and correct for. One of them is programming, one of them is CLI system admin. If you feel like calling them both programming, you could (a la REPL in Python etc), but it seems a little silly to consider `chkdsk c:` programming.

Comment: Yes, really. Calling "I want to do _____ with _____" illegal but "I want to do ____ with _____ *in a batch file*" legal is a poor decision.

Comment: @corsiKa: Then it's a good thing that's not what I said, at all, at all. What I did say was that *quirks* from batch file usage are decidedly on topic, and that other aspects directly relevant to and in the context of batching `xcopy`, while more dubious, are usually fine here. It's only when there isn't actually any programming involved that there's any reason to go "illegal".

Answer (score 15):

Your instinct is absolutely correct -- `xcopy` is a general-purpose command used by power users and system administrators without any programming involved.  Getting it to run (figuring out which switches, making sure permissions are set right, and so on) is completely unrelated to programming.

On the other hand, automating the command by including it in a loop, using variables, or capturing the exit code and using it to control flow... those are all on-topic programming tasks.  Even if the loop or variable is being typed at the command line, and not inside a batch file.  A programming language doesn't magically stop being a programming language because a REPL prompt is used.  But choosing command parameters doesn't become programming just because the command string is being passed to a spawn function.

The line is where **features of the command interpreter are being used**.  If the same command line could be pasted into the Win+R and/or "Shortcut Properties" dialogs and work correctly without a `cmd /c` prefix, it's not programming.

Then, the **tags should reflect the programming language and programming features** being used.  [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcopy) is not such, and has no place here.  It could be removed from all the on-topic questions without hurting anything.

Answer (score 4):

xcopy is often used to solve problems when writing installers, build systems, source code control etc.

All the above are on topic.

But just asking what flags to pass to xcopy is off-topic.

So

> I am trying to do XXX with xcopy

Is on topic, iff XXX is on topic.

[Post Build event xcopy - exclude some set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32044418/post-build-event-xcopy-exclude-some-set-of-files) is a good example of this.

Answer (score 0):

Just because it's on topic on a different site doesn't mean that it's *necessarily* off-topic on this site.

In this case, [xcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcopy) seems fundamentally programming-related to me, thus on-topic.

Answer (score -2):

Today **xcopy** became part of programming knowledge and part of every project because of automated builds and continual integration. It is something every programmer should now. That is why we shouldn't consider it off topic.

Comment: How to backup files, and how to send email,.are also things every programmer should know.  But they are off-topic, because they are not even slightly specific to programming.  Same for `xcopy`