# Are there any guidelines to determine whether a particular batch-file question should be asked here?

Tags: support, tags

Today I found [How can I eject a CD via the cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550656/how-can-i-eject-a-cd-via-the-cmd), tagged [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) & [eject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eject) (*the `eject` tag could use some burnation actually...*).

The question seems to be borderline off-topic as [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) questions are *on-topic* for Stack Overflow, but however the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info) makes no mention of any restrictions on using the tag:

> Tag usage
>
> The tag [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) can be used for programming-related problems in
> writing a batch script file for a Windows-based operating system.
> Please avoid "suggest a book"-type questions. Note the [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag
> is not to be used for questions referring to a "batch of files" but
> for questions related to the shell language only.

I know that some questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693076/how-to-force-delete-a-file)) have been closed due to this:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is
> not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do
> not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here.

Moreover, these questions are also on-topic on [Super User](http://superuser.com), and apparently a few have also been migrated there.

Are there *any* restrictions on using this tag?

Comment: Why should there be any restrictions?

Comment: Maybe a better question is, "Are there any guidelines to determine whether a particular batch-file question should be asked here vs. on Superuser?"

Comment: @Paebbels Many [tag:batch-file] questions are challenged with a range of 'this is off-topic/should be on super user', and indeed, the one I linked from yesterday was migrated to Super User shortly after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my response to [a similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305804/103167):

> [...] a general-purpose command used by power users and system administrators without any programming involved.  Getting it to run (figuring out which switches, making sure permissions are set right, and so on) is completely unrelated to programming.
>
> On the other hand, automating the command by including it in a loop, using variables, or capturing the exit code and using it to control flow... those are all on-topic programming tasks.  Even if the loop or variable is being typed at the command line, and not inside a batch file.  A programming language doesn't magically stop being a programming language because a REPL prompt is used.  But choosing command parameters doesn't become programming just because the command string is being passed to a spawn function.
>
> The line is where **features of the command interpreter are being used**.  If the same command line could be pasted into the Win+R and/or "Shortcut Properties" dialogs and work correctly without a `cmd /c` prefix, it's not programming.
>
> Then, the **tags should reflect the programming language and programming features** being used.  [...] is not such, and has no place here.  It could be removed from all the on-topic questions without hurting anything.

In fact, [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) is a surrender to common usage, shell scripting questions really should be tagged with the name of the shell ("Windows Command Interpreter" is the official name) and not merely "scripting" or "batch".  If the command sequence isn't specific to a single shell, it likely isn't programming.

Comment: As someone who has written a lot of batch files as part of my job as a programmer, I'm not sure expecting users to know the name of the shell they're using, let alone know to tag it with that, is reasonable; I have never heard of "Windows Command Interpreter" before, despite the above experience. I'm not an expert in batch files or shell scripting by any means... I just use Notepad and save as .bat.

Comment: Also, "*if the command sequence isn't specific to a single shell, it likely isn't programming*" this doesn't sound correct; if someone is writing a command for a computer to interpret, that's the *definition* of programming. JavaScript can be interpreted by any number of web browser engines (ignoring the many other things that can interpret JS... all more or less the same way), for example, but we consider that programming (or at least, we did the last time I checked).